# python ctypes throwing error?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

so far I've gotten a DLL that wasn't meant for python to work with it, and types return: I just can't pass it arguments because I'm doing it wrong and I don't quite understand the documentation on how I'm supposed to do things. Basically, the function in the DLL I'm testing is named "iptouint". It takes a c_char_p and returns a c_double.

Here is my code:

```
nDll = ctypes.WinDLL('ndll.dll')

nDllProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_double)
nDllInit = nDllProto(("dllInit", nDll))

nDllTestProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_double,ctypes.c_char_p)
nDllTest = nDllTestProto(("iptouint",nDll),((1, "p1",0),(1, "p2",0)))

#This is the line that throws the error:
print("IP: %s" % nDllTest("12.345.67.890"))

'''
It gives me the error:
ValueError: paramflags must have the same length as argtypes
Im not sure what to do; Ive certainly played around with it to no avail.
Help is much appreciated.
Thanks.
'''
```

Comment: Please,state the name and the  C documentation for the function you are actuallyt rying to call inside the "ndll"  dll.

Comment: @jsbueno Like I said, the function is named "iptouint" and takes a double and returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simply indicating ctypes the argtypes it takes and the ones it returns:

```
nDll = ctypes.WinDLL('ndll.dll')
nDll.restype = ctypes.c_double
nDll.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

result = nDll.iptouint("12.345.67.890").value
```

Although, consider these points:

1) if, as the name indicates, this converts an IPv4 value s ina  string to an Unsigned Int, the return type os not "double" as you say - it would be ctypes.c_uint32

2) Your example value is not a valit IPv4 address, and cannot be converted to a 32 bit integer (neither does it makes sense as a "double" - i.e. a 64 bit floating point number) - it is simply invalid

3) You don't need that if you are just trying to have an unsigned 32bit value for an ipv4 address in Python. There are quite a few, very readable, easier, and multiplatform ways to do that with pure python. For example:

```
def iptoint(ip):
   value = 0
   for component in ip.split("."):
       value <<= 8  #shifts previous value 8 bits to the left, 
                    #leaving space for the next byte
       value |= int(component)  # sets the bits for the new byte in the address
   return value
```

**update**:
In Python 3.x there is the ipaddress module -
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html - which is also available as  a pip install for Python 2.x - it can handle this always in the correct way, and works fine with IPv6 as well.

Comment: Yes - I had my IP in the slot and I simply covered it up. In addition, the DLL this was meant for only deals with strings and doubles. Once it's inside python it doesn't really make a difference.
Also, this was only one function. The DLL is actually a networking one that I find very usefull because it can read from a very unique message that I need to read from.
Thank you for your response. :) I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Wait - This code seems to only work well with a DLL that only has one function. Mine has many... is there any way I can keep it this easy and use all of the functions in the DLL?

Comment: You have to decaroate each function you will use so that cpython gets to known which parameters to send and to receive back. Otherwise, it just tries educated guesses - like "int" for any number, and "char_p" for anuy string you pass as a parameter (but it will assume the function returns an int anyway). Just set the argtypes and restype for each function you will use.